# Python, ElasticSearch/Kibana 'kibanaSavedObjectMeta' Visualization Metadata Index replace

Tags: python, elasticsearch, automation, scripting, kibana

Have a nice day, I hope anyone could help me find a solution to this. It would be very appreciated. I'm looking for a way to replace or Update an Elastic Visualization Metadata index, what I'm trying to accomplish is to automate with Python and update every Visualization Metadata index. Each of the indexes separately has a specific number of indexes, and for every Visualization I need to change these number of specific Indexes, for example, there are Visualizations that I may encounter that have 4 or 6 Indexes, and I need to replace or Update with new Indexes Automatically with a Script, here is my Script

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from common import handle_elasticsearch, finish_line, get_accounts, get_time
import creds
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q
import requests
from elasticsearch import helpers
import os, sys, json, unicodedata
import json



elastic_url = creds.elastic_url
elastic_auth = creds.elastic_http_auth
# def meta(loreal_instagram_contenido_bar):
es = handle_elasticsearch(elastic_url, elastic_auth)


def updater(es, visualization_name):
    
    query = {
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "filter": [
           {
             "term": {
               "visualization.title": visualization_name
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
    }
    raw_recolectados = es.search(index=".kibana", body=query, size=1)
    data = json.dumps(raw_recolectados)
    data = json.loads(data)


 data = data.replace('indexname','newindexname')
    return data
    
recolectados = updater(es, "visualization_bar_chart")
print (recolectados)
```

I made a function searching for the visualization passing the name of visualization as a parameter, if you can see the JSON there are two Indexes "keys", As I specific above I may encounter more than two indexes, and I need to replace all of that, the following response is only a piece of all the JSON response At my Console

```
'kibanaSavedObjectMeta':{  
                     'searchSourceJSON':'{\n  "index": "index_name_to_replace",\n  "query": {\n    "query": {\n      "match_all": {}\n    },\n    "language": "lucene"\n  },\n  "filter": [\n    {\n      "meta": {\n        "index": "index_name_to_replace",\n        "negate": false,\n        "disabled": false,\n        "alias": null,\n        "type": "phrase",\n        "key": "social_network.keyword",\n        "value": "ig",\n        "params": {\n          "query": "ig",\n          "type": "phrase"\n        }\n      },\n      "query": {\n        "match": {\n          "social_network.keyword": {\n
        "query": "ig",\n            "type": "phrase"\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      "$state": {\n        "store": "appState"\n
  }\n    }\n  ]\n}'
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

but when I trying Implement replace method I got:

```
file "updater.py", line 37, in updater
    data = data.replace('indexname', 'indexname')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

If anyone has a Shortcut Solution for this Type of problem/solution I WOULD BE very very Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hello for everyone who encounters this issue I just found a simple solution to modify the metadata, but you need to ingest back to Kibana (ES)

```
 text = data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['visualization']['kibanaSavedObjectMeta']['searchSourceJSON'].replace('index_of_visualization', 'new_index_name')
data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['visualization']['kibanaSavedObjectMeta']['searchSourceJSON'] = text
```